# asp.net 5 Session_start at startup file gone? how can I use it?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I use Session_Start, Session_end and Application_BeginRequest can't find it at Startup file.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpModules` have been replaced by [middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html?highlight=middleware) in `ASP.Net 5`
`Session_Start` and `Application_BeginRequest` are methods of `global.asax` which is an `Http_Module`.
So, to replace `Application_BeginRequest` you can write your own `middleware`.
By default, there isn't session in `ASP.Net 5`. You must add and configure the [session middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html?highlight=session) in your `Startup` to use it.